# What if editing my answer makes comments seem out of context?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, comments

I posted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823668/sap-business-objects-how-to-create-different-kinds-of-join-between-different-dat). After some additional comments from the OP I see that I misunderstood the question and I have a better answer.

Should I...

1. Leave my answer and add another one. SO discourages this.
2. Delete my answer and add another one.
3. Edit my answer and completely removing my prior answer. It would seem the comments on the answer will then be out of context and potentially confusing.
4. Edit my answer leaving the original answer and adding the new information.

Comment: #4 or #3 are the way to go, depending on how much of a change the OP makes to their criteria.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

5. Edit your answer so it is correct and says what you want; flag the comments so they can be deleted, since they are now obsolete.

Preservation of comments is not important. If in response you comments you improved your post, the comments served their purpose.

They can now be flagged for deletion.

Either flag them as "no longer needed", or if there are too many of them or you think a moderator may have trouble fully grasping the context by seeing the comment alone, use a custom flag explaining that the comments referred to a previous revision of your answer, and they can be deleted since they are stale or obsolete.

---

If by reading the comments you now think that the problem lies with *the question*, please encourage the asker to edit it so it's clearer and better adjusts to their intent. (You could *suggest* an edit, but you'd be dependent on the OP or other reviewers approving your edit.)

From your question I gather that you had misunderstood the question, not that the question was unclear to begin with and got clearer as comments were posted. If that's not the case, I guess additional steps may be needed.

Comment: I took a modified version of your approach and I added a comment to the original question. I started off by editing the original question itself, but I felt I was changing it too much.

Comment: @Isaac there's never changing too much, if the question is misleading about the issue at hand. Future readers then wouldn't be misled either thinking that the problem is something else.